# Divide whole dataframe by mean of control group for each of several sub-groups

Tags: r, dplyr

### Starting data

I'm working in R and I have a set of data generated from groups (cohorts) of animals treated with different doses of different drugs. A simplified reproducible example of my dataset follows:

```
# set starting values for simulation of animal cohorts across doses of various drugs with a few numeric endpoints
cohort_size <- 3
animals <- letters[1:cohort_size]
drugs <- factor(c("A", "B", "C"))
doses <- factor(c(0, 10, 100))
total_size <- cohort_size * length(drugs) * length(doses)

# simulate data based on above parameters
df <- cbind(expand.grid(drug = drugs, dose = doses, animal = animals),
            data.frame(
              other_metadata = sample(LETTERS[24:26], size = total_size, replace = TRUE),
              num1 = rnorm(total_size, mean = 10, sd = 3), 
              num2 = rnorm(total_size, mean = 60, sd = 9),
              num3 = runif(total_size, min = 1, max = 5)))
```

This produces something like:

```
##   drug dose animal other_metadata      num1     num2     num3
## 1    A    0      a              X  6.448411 54.49473 4.111368
## 2    B    0      a              Y  9.439396 67.39118 4.917354
## 3    C    0      a              Y  8.519773 67.11086 3.969524
## 4    A   10      a              Z  6.286326 69.25982 2.194252
## 5    B   10      a              Y 12.428265 70.32093 1.679301
## 6    C   10      a              X 13.278707 68.37053 1.746217
```

### My goal

For each drug treatment, I consider the `dose == 0` animals as my control group for that drug (let's say each was run at a different time and has it's own control group). I wish to calculate the mean for each numeric endpoint (columns 5:7 in this example) of the control group. Next I want to normalize (divide) every numeric endpoint (columns 5:7) for every animal by the mean of it's respective control group.

In other words `num1` for all animals where `drug == "A"` should be divided by the mean of `num1` for all animals where `drug == "A"` AND `dose == 0` and so on for each endpoint.

The final output should be the same size as the original `data.frame` with all of the non-numeric metadata columns remaining unchanged on the left side and all the numeric data columns now with the normalized values.

Naturally I'd like to find the simplest solution possible - minimizing creation of new variables and ideally in a single dplyr pipeline if possible.

### What I've tried so far

*I should say that I have technically solved this but the solution is super ugly with a ton of steps so I'm hoping to get help to find a more elegant solution.*

I know I can easily get the averages for the control groups into a new `data.frame` using:

```
df %>% 
  filter(dose == 0) %>%
  group_by(drug, dose) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

I've looked into several things but can't figure out how to implement them. In order of what seems most promising to me:

1. `dplyr::group_modify()`
2. `dplyr::rowwise()`
3. `sweep()` in some type of loop

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to divide the numeric columns by the `mean` of the control group values, grouped by 'drug', after grouping by 'drug', use `mutate` with `across` (from `dplyr` `1.0.0`), divide the column values (`.` with `mean` of the values where the 'dose' is 0

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
df %>% 
   group_by(drug) %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ./mean(.[dose == 0])))
```

If we have a dplyr version is `<` 1.0.0, use `mutate_if`

```
df %>%
    group_by(drug) %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ./mean(.[dose == 0]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! FWIW to others who use this solution, I ended up using `mutate_at([vector_of_positions]...` to address some nuance of the positions in my actual dataset which worked great.